# C# adding large bytearray(image) as paramter to dbcommand

Tags: c#, database

I'm currently in the process of creating a manual DB layer for a project. I've stumbled over a problem when I tried to store byte arrays (images) larger than 8k.

Normally I use the following to do create the commands and fill the parameters:

```
DbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (@mail, @picture)");
i=cmd.DeclareParameter(cmd, "mail", DbType.String, "mail");
if (i>0)
{
    cmd.Parameters[i].Value = mailData;
}
```

(The above is cut together from multiple methods I use). 
Now when I try to add the picture (which is the `byte[]`) I get the problem that I need to use `SqlDbType.VarBinary` there.

I've seen a few solutions that use `.Parameters.Add` but the Add I have only takes 1 (and not 2 parameters like in the examples I saw). Then when I try to create my own parameter with `cmd.CreateParameter` the `DbType` only takes a `DbType` and does not want an `SqlDbType`.

What would I have to do here to be able to add the `byte[]` as parameter (for byte arrays larger than 8k)?

tnx

Comment: Did you try [Parameters.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)? That will give you the ability to add a parameter with its associated value.

Comment: Thought about that already but according to C# The Parameters of the DbCommand I use does not have any AddWithValue

Answer (score 1):

Would SqlDbType.Image be more appropriate?

If not, consider [Row Overflowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx)

You're telling it to use DbCommand rather than SqlDbCommand.

Try this:

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (@mail, @picture)"))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(@"mail", SqlDbType.Image);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                command.Parameters[i].Value = mailData;
            }
        }
```

(I'd add this as a comment, but I can't so I shant.)

Comment: Part of my problem is that I can't use SqlDbType for parameters somehow (didnt find any method that lets me add a parameter that takes an sqldbtype instead of "only" an dbtype).

Comment: Updated my answer based on your response. You're casting SqlDbType as DbType which changes the options you can use. Note that I believe you should use '.image' because VarBinary limits to 8000

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to create my own parameter with cmd.CreateParameter the DbType only takes a DbType and does not want an SqlDbType

That's because you declared the command as a `DbCommand` instead of a `SqlCommand`.  If you declare it as a `SqlCommand` it should work:

```
|------
V
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (@mail, @picture)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", mailData);

SqlParameter p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
p.Value = {picture data};
```

Comment: Are there possible side effects of succh a change? (so far I only used either entity framework or dbcommand)

Comment: For entity framework you could add a byte array property to the class.

Comment: Not that I can think of since SqlCommand doesn't hide any DbCommand methods or properties that I can find.

Comment: ok one last question there after p.Value is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Wel lthat should get you to the end of your original code block, you still need to execute the command, get the results, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are really large you can consider streaming into the BLOB (image) column. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the length -1 for the parameter. Otherwise it will be `VARBINARY(8000)`. With an explicit length of -1 it will be `VARBINARY(MAX)`, which is what you need.